# .NET ToolStrip AutoSize wrong when padding not default

Tags: c#, .net, controls, toolstrip

When padding is default in ToolStrip then AutoSize works fine like this:

Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/538dSN4.png

But if I change padding then AutoSize calculates ToolStrip size wrong:

Screenshot 2: http://i.imgur.com/gfD2e4e.png

Because of language support I need to make this menu dynamic size. Is there a way to workaround this problem?

Edit:

```
        int size = 0;

        foreach (ToolStripItem tsi in tsMain.Items)
        {
            size = Math.Max(size, tsi.Width);
        }

        tsMain.Width = tsMain.Padding.Left + size + tsMain.Padding.Right;
```

Also tried this and it not gives expected result.